# add different fields to a JSON request to a subscription endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

For practicing tracking event, I need to integrate different fields to a JSON request to a subscription endpoint. Here are the 3 fields :

- "deviceType”: (string) “mobile”, “tablet” or “desktop”
- “userAgent”: (string) the direct value of navigator.userAgent
- “sourceForm”: (string) “top” or “bottom” ( I have two different button for the same action, to register, at the top and at the bottom of the page)

Here is the code :

```
function bindSubscriptionButton(btnId, nameId, emailId, nameErrorId, emailErrorId) {
            var button = document.getElementById(btnId);
            if (button) {
                button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    hideErrors();
                    var name = document.getElementById(nameId).value;
                    var email = document.getElementById(emailId).value;
                    var nameError = document.getElementById(nameErrorId);
                    var emailError = document.getElementById(emailErrorId);
                    if (!name) {
                        nameError.innerHTML = "Name ist erforderlich";
                        nameError.hidden = false;
                    }
                    if (!email) {
                        emailError.innerHTML = "E-Mail is required";
                        emailError.hidden = false;
                    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
                        emailError.innerHTML = "E-Mail is not valid";
                        emailError.hidden = false;
                    }
                    if (name && email && isEmailValid(email)) {
                        hideErrors();
                        sendDataToServer(name, email, undefined)
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        }
        bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton", "nameInput", "emailInput", "nameInputError", "emailInputError");
        bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton2", "nameInput2", "emailInput2", "nameInputError2", "emailInputError2");
    }

    function sendDataToServer(name, email, referralCode) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var response = this.response ? JSON.parse(this.response) : null;
                goToSuccessPage();
             }
        };
        var data = {
            email: email,
            firstName: name,
            lang: "en",
        };
        
        xhttp.open("POST", serverURL, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
```

I would like to add deviceType, userAgent and sourceForm to this object :

```
var data = {
                email: email,
                firstName: name,
                lang: "en",
            };
```

For the deviceType, I also need to pass this function :

```
const deviceType = () => {
    const ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobi))/i.test(ua)) {
        return "tablet";
    }
    else if (/Mobile|Android|iP(hone|od)|IEMobile|BlackBerry|Kindle|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Opera M(obi|ini)/.test(ua)) {
        return "mobile";
    }
    return "desktop";
};
```

For the sourceForm, I need to pass an extra argument for 'source' here :

```
bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton", "nameInput", "emailInput", "nameInputError", "emailInputError");
            bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton2", "nameInput2", "emailInput2", "nameInputError2", "emailInputError2");
```

and pass it through all the way to here :

```
if (name && email && isEmailValid(email)) {
                        hideErrors();
                        sendDataToServer(name, email, undefined)
                    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: 90% of this code looks like it's probably irrelevant to your question, please don't clutter the question, only post what's necessary. Anyway your requirement is a little unclear. What are you trying to "integrate" these values into. I guess maybe you want to the `data` variable? And what exact JSON would you expect at the end? It's also unclear where you're going to be getting the `sourceForm` value from. Please be clear and specific.

Comment: My bad , I made changes to make it clearer , hope it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'd have expected the `deviceType` function would still be relevant, since that's where you want to get at least one of the values from?

Comment: Absolutely, I accidentally deleted the function from my post.

Comment: Thankyou. See answer below, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "integrate" the values simply by setting more properties on the `data` object as you're creating it.

For the `sourceForm`, you can pass the value through into your `sendDataToServer` function via the `bindSubscriptionButton` function exactly as you described, and then set its value in your `data` object.

For the `deviceType` and `userAgent`, I would suggest modifying the `deviceType` function so it returns both the user agent string and the derived device type value in a single object. You can then copy the property values into equivalent properties in the `data` object.

For example:

```
bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton", "nameInput", "emailInput", "nameInputError", "emailInputError" "top");
bindSubscriptionButton("subscriptionButton2", "nameInput2", "emailInput2", "nameInputError2", "emailInputError2", "bottom");
```

and

```
function bindSubscriptionButton(btnId, nameId, emailId, nameErrorId, emailErrorId, sourceFrom) {
....
sendDataToServer(name, email, undefined, sourceFrom);
....
```

and

```
const deviceType = () => {
    const ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var devType = "";

    if (/(tablet|ipad|playbook|silk)|(android(?!.*mobi))/i.test(ua)) {
        devType = "tablet";
    }
    else if (/Mobile|Android|iP(hone|od)|IEMobile|BlackBerry|Kindle|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Opera M(obi|ini)/.test(ua)) {
        devType = "mobile";
    }
    else { devType = "desktop"; }

    return { "deviceType": devType, "userAgent": ua };
};
```

and

```
function sendDataToServer(name, email, referralCode, sourceFrom) {
....
    var dt = deviceType();

    var data = {
        email: email,
        firstName: name,
        lang: "en",
        deviceType: dt.deviceType,
        userAgent: dt.userAgent,
        sourceFrom: sourceFrom
    };
....
```